# How to Play .wav file when your execute a jar file in java.

Tags: java, audio, buttonclick

Do you know how to input a .wav file for a button click in java. this is my code.

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
 String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator;
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, path);


    InputStream in;
    try {           
        in  = new FileInputStream(new File(path+"Audios\\A.wav"));
         AudioStream audios = new AudioStream(in);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audios);

    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }

}
```

in this code when you run in in the netbeans and press execute. the wav file is playing. but when i clean build the solution and press the button from the jar file. The sound is not playing. I want a good reply for this question.

Comment: You should print any exceptions caught, so that you'll know what has gone wrong and can fix it (`e.printStackTrace()`).  Most likely, the wav file is not found at the path; you'll want to look into how to load a resource from a JAR.

Comment: @Vulcan I already did it. There was no exception throwing. When i run the Application in the Netbeans it is working Perfectly. But when i do a clean build and try to Run the Executable Jar file. It won't Work.

Comment: found a way on my own. thanks anyway